# Sharing via API on Facebook - differentiate between "success" and "canceled"?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

The documentation for Facebook's [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/) and [Share Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog/) suggest that if a user is not logged in to your app, you have no way of determining whether or not the user actually shared the story or just opened the dialog and clicked "Cancel".

My experimentation seems to match this behavior.  Can someone please confirm that this is the case?  (I would love it if I were wrong)

To clarify: I understand there's no way to receive `post_id` as a response if the user is not logged in (Facebook has deprecated this behavior).  **However, I'm surprised there's not even a way to determine if a post was actually shared or if the "Cancel" button was clicked...**

It seems like exposing this isn't a "privacy risk" for Facebook; having this success/canceled boolean available would be very useful in building a good UX.

Comment: why confirm something that you already tested and found out, and what´s even written in the api docs?

Comment: anyway, they probably made this for a good reason, it would be way too easy to force people to share something or to reward them in some way. which is not allowed. in generel, there is no reason for you to know if a user shared something. also, about building a good ux: you should let the user decide what to do, maybe he wants to use a share button twice to share something on different channels, for example.

Comment: @luschn - Documentation isn't always accurate, and is often easily misread.  It's happened to me even within the last week with Facebook's Graph API docs on a different aspect of the API.  It's certainly worth asking to see if someone with more experience knows of a different approach or if I'm missing something obvious.  Also, there definitely are valuable UX reasons to want this signal.  One simple example is to thank the user for sharing and supporting the site/app/etc.

Comment: yeah, but opening up the possibilty for people to do stuff that is not allowed easily is reason enough not to add a success callback just to thank users in serious apps ;)

Comment: Agreed! If the ability is available somehow, however, I will use it. I didn't open this question to try to get FB to change their API :)